# Is it possible to access variables and functions inside static methods of class in ES6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Firstly the code that will explain my query

```
class myClass {
    constructor() {
        this.myVariable = 10; 
    }

    myFunctionCalledFromStaticFunction() {
        console.log (`myFunctionCalledFromStaticFunction myvariable is ${this.myVariable}`);
    }

    static staticMyFunctionTwo() {
        console.log (`staticMyFunctionTwo myvariable is ${this.myVariable}`);
        this.myFunctionCalledFromStaticFunction();
    }

    static staticMyFunction() {
        console.log (`staticMyFunction myvariable is ${this.myVariable}`);
        myClass.staticMyFunctionTwo();
    }

    myFunctionTwo() {
        console.log (`myFunctionTwo myvariable is ${this.myVariable}`)
        myClass.staticMyFunction();
    }

    myFunction() {
        console.log (`myFunction myvariable is ${this.myVariable}`)
        this.myFunctionTwo();
    }
}

(function ($) {
    'use strict';
         const helloClass = new myClass();
         console.log (`main myvariable is ${helloClass.myVariable}`)
       helloClass.myFunction();  
       myClass.staticMyFunctionTwo();
}(jQuery));
```

And, now a codePen example https://codepen.io/hellouniverse/pen/jYyYre

Now, a disclaimer I have to give. **I have searched through stackoverflow, online and my own experience. I am quite certain it is not possible**.

If you take the code and run it or check in the codepen, you will notice that myVariable is undefined in static functions. Also, I can not call a normal function from a static function.

Am I correct in this statements? Or is it possible or has a workaround?

Comment: `this` doesn’t point to an instance of your class so you that’s why you can’t know the value of a variable that’s only available in an instance.

Comment: The same class can be re-used 100 times(instances). Each time myVariable can have a different value. A static must always be the same across all instances, therefor it would be impossible for a static method to use a non static variable because it can be different values at the same time. So what you want is static variables, which is possible but you'll need a workaround in JavaScript(out of scope for this question)

Comment: Here's a sanity check. Given that `myVariable` is not constant but depends on the instance like `this.myVariable = Math.random()`, what would you expect it to be equal to in static method?..

Comment: Inaccessible. So that would be undefined in JavaScript terms. Which value it in reality is should not matter to how you code your program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that you want to have accessible primitive data across the static and non-static methods. For such cases you would rather need to use `Symbol` or `const`.

How to use symbol you can read here: [MDN Symbol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol)

And your modified examples: [using `Symbol`](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ypgZXO?editors=1111) and [using the `const` keyword](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xpgMYp?editors=1111)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your codepen, the answer is no you cannot use `this` in a static function call, UNLESS you are calling another static method. As MDN points out, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static, you can have this

```
class Logger {
    static error(message) {
        this.log(message, 'error');
    }

    static log(message, level) {
        console[level](message);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a bit misleading IMO. The value of `this` depends on how the function is called. Of course if it’s called as `Class.method()`, then `this` reference to the constructor function itself. But it could also be called as `Class.method.call(obj)` (I’m not saying this is a good way) and `this` would refer to `obj`. Saying “you can’t *use* `this`” is wrong.

Comment: Remember that you should never have a `class` with only static methods. For that use case, just use an object literal.

Comment: @FelixKing yes you are correct with your statement You can always explicitly set the `this` context using call,apply,blind with the exception of an object created with the `new` keyword. I will beg you not to do something like this though myClass.staticMyFunction.call(new myClass());

Answer (score 1):

You have to understand what a class method desugars to. Consider

```
class Foo {
  static bar () {
    console.log(this.fooProp);
  }
};
```

Is more-or-less the same as this:

```
function Foo() {};
Foo.bar = function () { console.log(this.fooProp); };
```

Note that it isn't `Foo.prototype.bar`. Functions are Objects in JavaScript, and just like any other object when you call a method of an object (e.g. `Foo.bar()`) then `this` is set to the object it is called on (e.g. the function 'Foo', **not** an instance of Foo). I can say

```
Foo.fooProp = 3;
Foo.bar(); // logs 3
```

Without ever actually creating an instance of Foo. I can also call it from an instance

```
let foo = new Foo();
foo.constructor.bar(); // logs 3
```

But the `this` value will always refer to the class/constructor rather than the instance

```
foo.fooProp = 5;
foo.constructor.bar(); // still 3
```

Unless one does something like this:

```
Foo.bar.call(foo); // now it's 5
```